# Getting a "foreign key constraint fails" even though I have "on delete cascade"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, cascade

I thought the point of ON DELETE CASCADE was that this wouldn't happen. :\ I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Tweets (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID INTEGER                  NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(140)            NOT NULL,
    dateTime TIMESTAMP              NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    hasPoll INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    visible INTEGER                 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(userID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Polls (
    pollID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tweetID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pollOptionText VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (pollID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweets(tweetID)
);
```

The problem is that when I try to delete a Tweet which has a Poll attached to it, I get the following error (via Flask):

```
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError
IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`twitter`.`polls`, CONSTRAINT `polls_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tweetID`) REFERENCES `Tweets` (`tweetID`))')
```

Help please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is indeed the point of `on delete cascade`. You get the error, because your code *doesn't declare `on delete cascade`* from "poll" to "tweet".

```
CREATE TABLE Polls (
    pollID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tweetID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pollOptionText VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (pollID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweets(tweetID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This will delete rows in "Polls" when corresponding rows are deleted in "Tweets".

Comment: Thanks!! I thought "on delete cascade" went in the other direction, automatically applying to all tables which use a column of this table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `ON DELETE CASCADE` after `FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweets(tweetID)`

According to the [MySQL Foreign Key Constraints reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported.

Also, according to the [MySQL Foreign Keys reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines other than InnoDB, it is possible when defining a
>   column to use a REFERENCES tbl_name(col_name) clause, which has no
>   actual effect, and serves only as a memo or comment to you that the
>   column which you are currently defining is intended to refer to a
>   column in another table.

So since the foreign key is from the child table to the parent table, it makes foo a parent table and Polls a child table, so deleting a row from Tweets will cascade deletions to Pools, providing you use InnoDB or some other storage engine that supports it.

**UPDATE:**

This error is because you have a relation between poll and twitter... without cascading you have to delete or update the polls removing the relation with the Tweet that will be deleted. Or use `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tweets (
    tweetID INTEGER                 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    content VARCHAR(140)            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweetID)
);

CREATE TABLE Polls (
    pollID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tweetID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pollOptionText VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (pollID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tweetID) REFERENCES Tweets(tweetID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Tweets VALUES(1,'tweet');
INSERT INTO Polls VALUES(1,1,"pool");
DELETE FROM Tweets WHERE tweetID = 1;
```

Comment: "so deleting a row from Tweets will cascade deletions to Pools, providing you use InnoDB or some other storage engine that supports it." 
Yes, exactly... so why is it an error then? I want to delete some tweet which has some poll attached to it, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: This error is because you have a relation between poll and twitter... without cascading you have to delete or update the polls removing the relation with the Tweet that will be deleted. Or use `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

You will surely get this error. you have to keep at least one record into tweets.